# Office-JS Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am having trouble with using Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged for Outlook.

I've tested this on Windows and Outlook.com. Mac apparently does not support 1.7 yet.

This is the error I get when I use the following code block:
**Function addHandlerAsync has invalid parameters.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
try {
    if(Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('MailBox', '1.7')) {
        console.log('MailBox 1.7 supported');
        Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged, function(result){
          if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                console.log("Error with event handler.");
          }
            else {
                processRecipientsChanged();
            }
    });
}

}catch(e){
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Is this behaviour common for both win32 and outlook web platform?

Comment: I have tested this on Outlook Web Platform and can confirm that it throws the exception above from looking at the console. I cannot confirm that the Window32 platform throws the same exception (I did not have a way to debug/view the console from the Win laptop I was trying it out with) but I know the callback does not get called and if I remove the try/catch, the add-in crashes so I assume that it behaves the same.   Also, if I change the above code to use Office.EventType.ItemChange, the code runs fine but that is not the event I need.

Comment: Since RecipientsChanged events occur in the item scoped, the call is Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/office.context.mailbox.item#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that! Thanks so much. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Since RecipientsChanged events occur in the item scoped, the call is Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/office.context.mailbox.item#addhandlerasynceventtype-handler-options-callback

Comment: Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync instead of Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync